# Recording from your set top box directly to a laptop

Tags: hdmi, tv, high-definition

I have a HD set top box and a HD PVR 2 gaming edition plus. The HD set top box has scart and HDMI.

I want to record footage from my set top box directly to my laptop. But I get the message: HD protection.

What I've done is:

- attach set top box with HDMI cable to the HDMI input of the HD PVR.
- attach the HD PVR with HDMI cable to my TV
- attach the HD PVR with USB cable to my laptop

Is there a possibility to record directly to laptop from a set top box?

Maybe if I use a scart to HDMI convertor and connect the set top box with a scart cable to the 'scart to HDMI converter' and then with a HDMI cable to my TV?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"HD protection" means [HDCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-bandwidth_Digital_Content_Protection) is in use on the video feed you're trying to record, and it's purpose is to prevent recording (weak protection against Blu-Ray copying, but looks like it didn't make a big difference when we look at how many perfect-quality BD rips are out there on the internet).

One solution would be to try to find modified firmware for your HD PVR that cracks the HDCP protection (I'm pretty sure it has been broken already like every single copy protection attempt made so far), but that's hard and such firmware may not even exist - you may have more luck under Linux if your PVR is supported and you can dump the raw HDMI data and do the actual cracking on the computer itself.

Another solution would be to use SCART as your say, but it is analog and has a very low resolution compared to HDMI - however you want to use a SCART->HDMI converter, these devices most likely exist but they're expensive, it would be way cheaper to buy an analog capture card (equivalent of your HD PVR) and use a passive converter to convert the SCART into something accepted by that capture card (most likely [RCA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RCA_connector) or [S-Video](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-Video)).

The best solution would be to completely get rid of the set-top-box and use the computer instead, if it uses standard TV signals like DVB, you can buy a tuner that will allow your computer to act as the set top box and receive the TV signal. If the signal is encrypted it's still possible if your set-top-box uses a [conditional access smart card](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional-access_module) which can be used on a computer without any problems.

Comment: But those SCART to HDMI converters, don't they give also a nice quality? And I'm wondering if the HD protection will appear again with such a converter, because HDMI is also involved..

Comment: @Gilko [take a small picture](https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQQZQVdSFUIjxXuBsP4tiEkrgLdHxvQ6KnLrCLQonvbmo-q_lID) and try to zoom in on it... the only thing you get is a bad quality picture. The SCART->HDMI converted will do the same, zoom in on the small 640x480 (approximately - I don't know the exact resolution but it's not higher than that) to make it 1920x1080. However HDCP won't be an issue since there's no HDCP on SCART (physically impossible) and the converter itself has no point in adding HDCP.

Comment: I've been searching for a solution a while now but can't seem to find one. I just want to be able to record HD tv directly on my laptop.

Comment: @Gilko see my "best solution", but that requires a standard TV signal (no IPTV since there's no standards for it yet and each company uses their own proprietary protocols and stuff) and if encryption is present then it also requires a smart-card to decrypt it, if you have one it would be inserted into the card reader of you set top box.